# The alpha parameter of focal loss

Tags: loss-functions, unbalanced-classes, object-detection

I want to use a weighted focal loss for my imbalanced object detection problem.

\begin{equation}
L = - \alpha(1-\hat{p})^\gamma log(\hat{p})  , \ \hat{p} =     \begin{cases} 
      p, & \text{if}\ y=1 \\
      1-p, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases} 
 \end{equation}

Now, according to the  [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002?fbclid)

"A common method for addressing class imbalance is to
introduce a weighting factor α ∈ [0, 1] for class 1 and 1 − α
for class −1. In practice α may be set by inverse class frequency or treated as a hyperparameter to set by cross validation. "

They also propose an $\alpha$ of 0.25.

My question is possibly silly, but I cannot understand why an *inverse* frequency favors the rarer class. Can someone explain why or how I've got it backwards?